# recyclerview fast scroll not works after touch event

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, nestedscrollview

I have an recyclerview inside nestedscrollview and I can scroll the recyclerview with touch event. But my problem is when I scroll fastly the recyclerview, after picking up my finger, the scrolling stops. But what I want is, it will slide depending on my finger's speed.

Here is my layout: 
item_container_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="true"
        android:id="@+id/container_list">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am inflating this with a fragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_container_list,container,false);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.container_list);

    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    //recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SimpleDividerItemDecoration(this.getContext()));

    return view;
}
```

Here is video: https://youtu.be/OCu7Nobvblc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to it after adding this to your `onCreateView` method :-

```
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Comment: puff, I want to cry :-) Thank you.

Comment: Yes, i am researching this on the internet for two days. I tried this but now it works. After 4 minutes i will be able to accept your answer. Thank you so much.

Comment: Great! I'm glad that it works. And thank you for the acceptance.